# What is the impact of adding an emoticon to an app title?

Tags: google-play

Is there research that shows that adding an emoticon into an Android app title impacts (positively or negatively) the App Store Optimization (ASO) and conversion rate?

What is the conclusion?

Comment: We can tell you about how to make the game parts of your game better. For app store ranking advice, your best bet may be to consult a Ouija board.

Comment: @DMGregory Ouija boards may cause depression. :p

Comment: Magic 8 ball then?